# In a razor project what is the differrence between Content Page, Empty Page and Web Page Razor

Tags: razor, html

I am new to Web Pages and have just started learning it.. After creating a new Razor website, when I click on add new item I get multiple options of the items I can add. Those are:

- **Layout Page(Razor)** These are similar to Master Pages
- **Helper(Razor)** These are used to create certain repeatedly building blocks
- **Content Page(Razor)**
- **Empty Page(Razor)**
- **Web Page(Razor)**

I don't know what are these last 3 used for and the difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Content Page** is one the makes use  of a layout page. It contains a code block and a `div`. No `head` or `body` elements.

**Empty Page** is a Razor file (.cshtml/.vbhtml) with nothing but a code block in it (no HTML)

**Web Page** is a Razor file with no code blocks in it, just HTML.

Comment: does that means that **Content Page** can have both HTML and Razor code  **Empty Page** is specially designed to handle Razor code **Web Page** is used for designing..

Comment: You can add HTML to the Empty Page and set a lyaout page, making it a content page and you can add Razor code to a Web Page and add a RenderBody call to it, making it a layout page, and so on. They are just different starting points to help you achieve whatever you need.